# Can't print contents after scraping site

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, html-table

I am unable to print contents after scraping a website using selenium. I need to scrape a table. Here's what I am trying to do:

```
table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="line-chart"]/div/div[1]/div/div/table/tbody')

print table.text
```

But I am just getting a blank line!!

I know I am selecting the correct contents because when I save an html file it works fine:

```
source_code = table.get_attribute("outerHTML")
f = open('html_source.html', 'w')
f.write(source_code.encode('utf-8'))
f.close()
```

And I get:

```
<tbody><tr><td>‪Jun 19‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 20‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 21‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 22‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 23‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 24‬</td><td>57</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 25‬</td><td>11</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 26‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 27‬</td><td>39</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 28‬</td><td>31</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 29‬</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jun 30‬</td><td>28</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 1‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 2‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 3‬</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 4‬</td><td>4</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 5‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 6‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 7‬</td><td>22</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 8‬</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 9‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 10‬</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 11‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 12‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 13‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 14‬</td><td>28</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 15‬</td><td>25</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 16‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 17‬</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 18‬</td><td>28</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 19‬</td><td>28</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 20‬</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 21‬</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 22‬</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 23‬</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 24‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 25‬</td><td>35</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 26‬</td><td>92</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 27‬</td><td>100</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 28‬</td><td>50</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 29‬</td><td>39</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 30‬</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>‪Jul 31‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 1‬</td><td>32</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 2‬</td><td>35</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 3‬</td><td>31</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 4‬</td><td>33</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 5‬</td><td>33</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 6‬</td><td>10</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 7‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 8‬</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 9‬</td><td>32</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 10‬</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 11‬</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 12‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 13‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 14‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 15‬</td><td>34</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 16‬</td><td>33</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 17‬</td><td>29</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 18‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 19‬</td><td>25</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 20‬</td><td>12</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 21‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 22‬</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 23‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 24‬</td><td>24</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 25‬</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 26‬</td><td>21</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 27‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 28‬</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 29‬</td><td>24</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 30‬</td><td>43</td></tr><tr><td>‪Aug 31‬</td><td>27</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 1‬</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 2‬</td><td>23</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 3‬</td><td>7</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 4‬</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 5‬</td><td>5</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 6‬</td><td>26</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 7‬</td><td>72</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 8‬</td><td>53</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 9‬</td><td>37</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 10‬</td><td>9</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 11‬</td><td>6</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 12‬</td><td>30</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 13‬</td><td>35</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 14‬</td><td>44</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 15‬</td><td>54</td></tr><tr><td>‪Sep 16‬</td><td>53</td></tr></tbody>
```

Comment: Try using `table.get_attribute("textContent")`

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot. Why would this work and not .text??

Comment: It's hard to say, why .text not work in your case, may be its designing issue..I have provided it's as answer you can mark this as correct as well. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say, why `.text` is not working in your case, may be its designing issue. But you can try also using `get_attribute()` to scrap text as below :-

```
table.get_attribute("textContent")
```